# How to handle polymorphism in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, polymorphism, abstract-class

I am working with an abstract class and two concrete ones, which implementing the abstract one. The diagram is as the next:
[image]

My classes looks as:

```
abstract class NavItem() {
    var attributes: String = ""
    var text = ""
}

class NavMenu(val items: MutableList<NavItem>) : NavItem()

class NavLink(var shortText: String) : NavItem()
```

The problem is when I try to work with the items which could be NavMenu or NavLinks, the NavMenus has a collection of NavLinks.

I am trying to work with the items using polymorphism as the next code:

```
navMenu.items.forEach{ item ->
            buildNavItem(item)
        }
```

the buildNavItem methods seems as:

```
private fun buildNavItem(navMenu: NavMenu){
        navMenu.items
        navMenu.attributes
        navMenu.items
    }

    private fun buildNavItem(navItem: NavItem){
        navItem.text
        navItem.attributes
    }

    private fun buildNavItem(navLink: NavLink){
        navLink.text
        navLink.attributes
    }
```

But the code is always getting into buildNavItem(navItem: NavItem), even when in the for each I can see sometimes that the item is NavLink, or is NavMenu.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!!

Comment: Polymorphism works only on the receiver object: if you call navItem.foo(), then the foo() method of NavMenu will be called if navItem is indeed a NavMenu. It doesn't work on overloaded methods as you're trying to do. The overloaded method isalways chosen at compile time, based on the declared type of the variable passed as argument.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Problem:**

```
navMenu.items.forEach { item ->
    item.buildNavItem()
}
```

Since `items` is of type `List<NavMenu>`, the compiler will call the function which is appropriate for an `item` of type `NavMenu`, in this case the overload which takes a `NavMenu`.

**Solution:**

In order to call a more specific overload the compiler needs to know the type. You can smart cast the items an the appropriate function will be called:

```
private fun buildNavItem(navMenu: NavMenu) {
   when(navMenu){
      is NavItem -> buildNavItem(navMenu) // navMenu is smart casted to NavItem
      is NavLink -> buildNavItem(navMenu) // navMenu is smart casted to NavLink
      else -> throw IllegalStateException("Unknown subtype ${navMenu::class.simpleName} of NavMenu")
   }
}
```

This way whenever you call `buildNavItem`, you delegate to the appropriate function.

Answer (score 5):

That is not how polymorphism works. You have `navMenu.items` list that is the type of `MutableList<NavItem>`, it can store `NavItem`s or its descendants. In `forEach` function you go through each item, which has `NavItem` type, and call `buildNavItem(item)` function. In this case `buildNavItem(navItem: NavItem)` is always called. To call the same method with another parameter you need to explicitly cast it to that type. What I recommend, and that's how polymorphism works, is to create `buildNavItem()` function in `NavItem` class and implement it in descendants:

```
abstract class NavItem() {
    var attributes: String = ""
    var text = ""
    abstract fun buildNavItem()
}

class NavMenu(val items: MutableList<NavItem>) : NavItem() {
    override fun buildNavItem() {
        // ... your concrete implementation for NavMenu
    }
}

class NavLink(var shortText: String) : NavItem() {
    override fun buildNavItem() {
        // ... your concrete implementation for NavLink
    }
}
```

And then you can call it in `forEach` function:

```
navMenu.items.forEach { item ->
        item.buildNavItem()
}
```

In that case `buildNavItem()` function will be called for the right object, that is stored in `navMenu.items`, i.e. if it is an object of `NavLink` type then function 'buildNavItem()', overridden in `NavLink` class, will be called.